# Django MOD_WSGI Settings ? MOD_WSGI Apache2 403 You don't have permission to access this resource

Tags: python, django, deployment, apache2, mod-wsgi

I'm testing an app on **Ubuntu Server 18.04(VirtualBox)** before bought VPS service. This is my **first deployment** even if it's a test and on VB.
I'm facing some kind of Apache WSGI error.

**Error: You don't have permission to access this resource Apache/2.4.29 (Ubuntu) Server at 192.xxx.xx.xxx Port 80**

Before WSGI setup, i did run few test at 8000 port and it was running well. When i setup the WSGI on the server i can't get app running.

App and venv located under /home/alp/diricanelektronik directory. My server username: **alp** and app name is **diricangrup**

(I did change conf file and restart apache service)
My head is about to explode. **You are my last hope, please help me**

ufw status:

```
22/tcp                     ALLOW       Anywhere
80/tcp                     ALLOW       Anywhere
22/tcp (v6)                ALLOW       Anywhere (v6)
80/tcp (v6)                ALLOW       Anywhere (v6)
```

app home directory:
(/home/alp/diricanelektronik/diricangrup)

```
├── contact
│   ├── admin.py
│   ├── apps.py
│   ├── forms.py
│   ├── models.py
│   ├── tests.py
│   └── views.py
├── db.sqlite3
├── diricangrup
│   ├── asgi.py
│   ├── settings.py
│   ├── urls.py
│   └── wsgi.py
├── manage.py
├── media
├── references
│   ├── admin.py
│   ├── apps.py
│   ├── forms.py
│   ├── models.py
│   ├── tests.py
│   └── views.py
├── requirements.txt
├── static
│   ├── css
│   │   ├── mobile.css
│   │   ├── references.css
│   │   └── style.css
├── staticfiles
│   │── css
│      ├── mobile.css
│      ├── references.css
│      └── style.css 
│       
└── templates
    ├── base.html
    ├── includes
    │   ├── footer.html
    │   └── navbar.html
    ├── index.html
    └── references.html
```

File permissions:

```
/home/alp
drwxrwxr-x 4 alp  www-data 4096 Nov 24 11:09 diricanelektronik


/home/alp/diricanelektronik

drwxrwxr-x 4 alp www-data 4096 Nov 24 11:09 .
drwxr-xr-x 6 alp alp      4096 Nov 23 22:25 ..
drwxrwxr-x 9 alp www-data 4096 Nov 24 14:27 diricangrup
drwxrwxr-x 6 alp alp      4096 Nov 23 22:41 venv



/home/alp/diricanelektronik/diricangrup

drwxrwxr-x 9 alp www-data   4096 Nov 24 14:27 .
drwxrwxr-x 4 alp www-data   4096 Nov 24 11:09 ..
drwxrwxr-x 4 alp alp        4096 Nov 23 22:16 contact
-rw-rw-r-- 1 alp www-data 139264 Nov 24 11:44 db.sqlite3
drwxrwxr-x 3 alp alp        4096 Nov 23 22:53 diricangrup
-rw-rw-r-- 1 alp alp         689 Nov 23 22:16 manage.py
drwxrwxr-x 2 alp www-data   4096 Nov 24 11:44 media
drwxrwxr-x 4 alp alp        4096 Nov 23 22:16 references
-rw-rw-r-- 1 alp alp         100 Nov 23 22:16 requirements.txt
drwxrwxr-x 6 alp alp        4096 Nov 23 22:16 static
drwxrwxr-x 7 alp alp        4096 Nov 23 22:16 staticfiles
drwxrwxr-x 3 alp alp        4096 Nov 24 11:35 templates



/home/alp/diricanelektronik/diricangrup/diricangrup

drwxrwxr-x 3 alp alp      4096 Nov 23 22:53 .
drwxrwxr-x 9 alp www-data 4096 Nov 24 14:27 ..
-rw-rw-r-- 1 alp alp         0 Nov 23 22:16 __init__.py
drwxrwxr-x 2 alp alp      4096 Nov 23 22:53 __pycache__
-rw-rw-r-- 1 alp alp       415 Nov 23 22:16 asgi.py
-rw-rw-r-- 1 alp alp      3950 Nov 23 22:53 settings.py
-rw-rw-r-- 1 alp alp      1241 Nov 23 22:16 urls.py
-rw-rw-r-- 1 alp alp       415 Nov 23 22:16 wsgi.py
```

WSGI conf file:

```
        Alias /static /home/alp/diricanelektronik/diricangrup/staticfiles
        <Directory /home/alp/diricanelektronik/diricangrup/staticfiles>
                Require all granted
        </Directory>

        Alias /media /home/alp/diricanelektronik/diricangrup/media
        <Directory /home/alpcusta/diricangrup/media>
                Require all granted
        </Directory>

        <Directory /home/alpcusta/diricanelektronik/diricangrup/diricangrup>
                <Files wsgi.py>
                        Require all granted
                </Files>
        </Directory>

        WSGIScriptAlias / /home/alpcusta/diricanelektronik/diricangrup/diricangrup/wsgi.py
        WSGIDaemonProcess django_app python-path=/home/alp/diricanelektronik/diricangrup python-home=/home/alp/diricanelektronik/venv
        WSGIProcessGroup django_app
```

and

```
ALLOWED_HOSTS = ['192.xxx.xx.xxx','127.0.0.1']
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I have tried few thing and didn't work then i decided to remove **apache2** and **libapache2-mod-wsgi-py3** and reinstall. Also deleted project files from server

To remove:

```
sudo apt-get purge apache2 libapache2-mod-wsgi-py3
```

Re-install:

```
sudo apt-get install apache2 libapache2-mod-wsgi-py3
```

Send project from windows to ubuntu server:

```
scp -P 22 -r django-project user@ipadress:/home/user
```

Conf file

```
cd /etc/apache2/sites-available/ && cp 000-default.conf django.conf && sudo nano django.conf

        Alias /static /home/user/django-project/django-project/staticfiles
        <Directory /home/user/django-project/django-project/staticfiles> 
            Require all granted
        </Directory>


        Alias /media /home/user/django-project/django-project/media
        <Directory /home/user/django-project/django-project/media> 
            Require all granted
        </Directory>

        #
        <Directory /home/user/django-project/django-project/django-project>
            <Files wsgi.py>
                Require all granted
            </Files>
        </Directory>


        WSGIScriptAlias / /home/user/django-project/django-project/django-project/wsgi.py
        WSGIDaemonProcess django_app python-path=/home/user/django-project/django-project python-home=/home/user/django-project/venv
        WSGIProcessGroup django_app
```

After all of this

```
sudo chown :www-data django-project/db.sqlite3 #(make apache the group owner)
sudo chmod 664 django-project/db.sqlite3       
sudo chown :www-data django-project   #main app dir
sudo chmod 775 django-project         #main app dir

sudo chown -R :www-data django-project/media/
sudo chmod -R 775 django-project/media
```

Restart apache2

```
systemctl reload apache2
sudo service apache2 restart
```

Basically same things that i did before, however this time it's works(**error due to file access permissions**)